# How to install and maintain 2 versions of sbt(say 1.2.7 and 1.2.8) on windows 10 without any library issues?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working on 2 different projects in which the sbt version of project-1 in build.properties is 1.2.7 and the project-2 is 1.2.8, and I cannot make both versions of sbt in build.properties the same.
As a workaround 'how can I maintain 2 sbt versions on my windows 10 to run those 2 projects separately?
Thank you All in Advance.

Comment: You do not need to, sbt is recursive, that means sbt builds the sbt used to build your project. The version you put in the properties file is the version that will be built to build your project. You can have any _(compatible)_ version installed on your machine, and use that for your two projects.

Comment: I have a Project1 with sbt version in the build file: 1.2.8 which is working fine with sbt package command. The Project2 has sbt version as 1.2.7, but when I run the sbt package its not resolving the dependencies and throwing an ERROR
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.11.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbteclipse#sbteclipse-plugin;5.1.2: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: org.scoverage#sbt-scoverage;1.3.3: not found

Comment: To Add to the above comment, I am using a proxy to connect to different repos and also installed all the required certificates in cacerts to pull the library jars. The Proxy and certificates are working fine for Project1 and sbt package is running successfully with no issues. 
But in case of Project 2, the dependencies are not getting resolved, which bring me to an idea of installing 2 versions of sbt on windows machine.

Comment: [There is **NO** sbt-assembly v`0.11.2` for SBT `1.0`](https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/), however [there is one for SBT `0.13`](https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/), the same goes for [sbteclipse](https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/) _(however that version does not even exist)_ and for [scoverage](https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbteclipse/sbteclipse-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/).

Comment: The problem is not having two different sbt versions, the problem is that the versions of the plugins you are using _(apart of being hell of outdated)_ are not published for the version of SBT that the project itself is using _(why does the project uses versions that does even exists is a good question to make to your teammates)_. Consider upgrade the dependencies _(which IMHO is the best idea)_ or downgrade the project sbt version to `0.13.x`, your system SBT should be the latest release.

Comment: Great Luis,
Here is mine
plugin.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "0.10.1")
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "5.2.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
assembly.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
build.properties.
sbt.version=1.2.8

Comment: Hello Luis, thank you for your help.
I am able to overcome it with the below plugin.sbt,
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.0")
// addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.2.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")
I've commented out scoverage, for time being.

Was able to resolve the above dependencies, and now I am kind of working my way through below issue,
val sharedMergeStrategy: (String => MergeStrategy) => String => MergeStrategy =
                ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression

Comment: I believe it would be better to create a new question, on that one provide all details like sbt version, plugin version, scala version, etc. Better yet create an post a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes Luis, I will probably refer to that on creating a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sbt project version does not need to match the installed sbt version. When you start sbt on a project that specifies v1.2.8 in its `build.properties`, the sbt launcher will download the appropriate sbt version if necessary and build your project with it. This mechanism is both backward and forward compatible.

Plugins in a given sbt project must be compatible with the version declared in `build.properties`, but not necessarily with the installed version.